# Flutter: onDismissed

Tags: dart, flutter

I was wondering if there is a chance to implement on Flutter a function similar to onDismissed that by sliding to the left will trigger a function, and to the right something else?
As so far all I could find by doing some research, is to remove items from the list, but nothing more than trigger more than one function.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `Dismissible` `Widget`.

`Dismissible` calls `onDismissed` when you swipe in the specified `direction`.

```
Dismissible(
  direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
  child: child, // all your content that will be swiped away 
  onDismissed: (direction) {
    if(direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
      // dismissed to the left
    }
  },
);
```